# Solve maze using queue data structure?

Tags: c, data-structures, queue

I'm taking a class in data structures and was given the assignment to find the shortest path through a maze using C and implementing the queue data structure. However, I can't really wrap my head around how to use a queue here.

I know the idea is to count every possible move from the start position, and when you hit the target, you're supposed to trace back to the initial position. This is what I don't understand. Because if I use a queue and delete all the moves that leads up to the target, I have no data to use to do the trace back, and if I don't delete the moves that lead to the target (i.e. saving all the possible moves and deleting them when I actually do the trace back), I might as well be using a stack.

I know there's something I don't quite get, but I can't figure out what it is. How would I utilize the queue data structure in this case?

Comment: If you're down-voting, please explain why the question was poorly asked. I'm not asking you to write me code. I'm asking you to point me in the right direction so I can write the code myself.

Comment: Have you tried googling it before posing here?

Comment: @rootTraveller Ya of course, and if I had found a good enough answer that I could understand, I wouldn't have asked it. I'm asking because I don't fully understand despite having heard/read other explanations. 

Nevertheless, if you have an answer to my question or some kind of explanation that you think would benefit me, googled or not, I would love to hear about it. And again, it's not so much about the solution itself, but rather about how it is explained.

Comment: As Lorenzo said, `BFS` is always better choice for finding shortest path.  once you reached the destination, the cost is minimum, hence you should clear the queue.

Comment: further reading http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/81802/shortest-path-through-a-maze

Answer (score 2):

What your professor is trying to get you to use is called "breadth-first search". The queue comes in for deciding which spaces to explore next. When you are looking at the possible paths to take, you enqueue all the paths you have yet to explore. Instead of continuing down the path you're on (which would be "depth-first search"), you dequeue the next spot you need to check, which will take you back to one of the positions you were considering earlier.

The actual implementation is up to you, I'd recommend looking for examples of breadth-first search online.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

So, if I'm at the start position, would that mean I have the entire maze enqueued (except the invalid locations, i.e. "walls") and then dequeue that position?

Comment: @Lobs001 Not quite, when you're at the start, you would only have the adjacent positions enqueued. Then, when you visit one of these positions you would enqueue the next positions, but next items in the queue are still the other ones closest to the start. It's hard to describe, I'd recommend looking up videos for 'bfs pathfinding algorithms' or something.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll look into the stuff you recommended and give it another go.